# Why are closed questions shown an option to protect?

Tags: support, protected-questions

When we reach a reputation of 15k, we are able to protect a question. Intention behind this privilege is preventing questions from getting non spam answers and low quality answers when the question is too popular.

But when a question is closed (not put on-hold) and there's no possibility of getting answered.

> [image: picture of a closed question with protect on it]

What is the point of adding an option to protect a closed question? Is it a feature intended as a preventive measure so that it will be protected even if a question is later reopened after some modifications?,

Comment: This is in case the question is later reopened.